# react/axios Auth and CORS issue

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, cors, axios

Using:

**Back:** Laravel/Passport
**Front:** ReactJs/Axios

I want to get data in my page, and if I run:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/posts')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error ' + error);
  });
```

> GET http://localhost:8000/api/posts net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:8000/api/posts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.

**And if I add:**

```
 headers: {
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
  crossDomain: true,
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/posts' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

**In laravel/ api.php:**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('posts', 'PostController@index');
});
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Route::group([ 'middleware' => [ \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class ]], function() {
        Passport::routes();
    });
```

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
$this->mapApiRoutes();

$this->mapWebRoutes();

Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth:api', 'cors'],
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    'prefix' => 'auth:api',
], function ($router) {
    Route::apiResource('posts','PostController');
});
```

But if I remove `headers` from `axios` and also move `route` outside of passport auth, it work fine, I mean like this outside of group:

```
Route::get('posts', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'PostController@index'));
```

So, how can I get data from Laravel API with passport auth with axios in reactjs?

**UPDATE:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth:api', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function(){

    Route::get('posts', 'PostController@index');
});
```

> 404 (Not Found)

I used `cors` on group too, but still the same and 404 error.

Comment: you are missing the `cors` middleware on the group.

Comment: @DavinTryon I added cors to group on `RouteServiceProvider.php` and also `AuthServiceProvider.php` nothing different

Comment: In your middleware try putting `cors` as first one..

Comment: @Panther See my answer updated

Comment: use something like `Route::group([  'middleware' => ['cors', 'auth:api'],...`

Comment: @Panther still the same

Answer (score 0):

For allowing CORS we must enable request on both side as server side and also on client side 
Might be it help 
add in request header section in axios

`headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}`

and for routes add

```
Route::options(
    '/{any:.*}', 
    [
        'middleware' => ['CorsMiddleware'], 
        function (){ 
            return response(['status' => 'success']); 
        }
    ]
);
```

and CorsMiddleware.php will be like as

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    protected $settings = array(
        'origin' => '*',    // Wide Open!
        'allowMethods' => 'GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
    );

    protected function setOrigin($req, $rsp) {
        $origin = $this->settings['origin'];
        if (is_callable($origin)) {
            // Call origin callback with request origin
            $origin = call_user_func($origin,
                        $req->header("Origin")
                    );
        }
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
    }

    protected function setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['exposeHeaders'])) {
            $exposeHeaders = $this->settings['exposeHeaders'];
            if (is_array($exposeHeaders)) {
                $exposeHeaders = implode(", ", $exposeHeaders);
            }

            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', $exposeHeaders);
        }
    }

protected function setMaxAge($req, $rsp) {
    if (isset($this->settings['maxAge'])) {
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', $this->settings['maxAge']);
    }
}

protected function setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp) {
    if (isset($this->settings['allowCredentials']) && $this->settings['allowCredentials'] === True) {
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    }
}

protected function setAllowMethods($req, $rsp) {
    if (isset($this->settings['allowMethods'])) {
        $allowMethods = $this->settings['allowMethods'];
        if (is_array($allowMethods)) {
            $allowMethods = implode(", ", $allowMethods);
        }

        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', $allowMethods);
    }
}

protected function setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp) {
    if (isset($this->settings['allowHeaders'])) {
        $allowHeaders = $this->settings['allowHeaders'];
        if (is_array($allowHeaders)) {
            $allowHeaders = implode(", ", $allowHeaders);
        }
    }
    else {  // Otherwise, use request headers
        $allowHeaders = $req->header("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    }
    if (isset($allowHeaders)) {
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $allowHeaders);
    }
}

protected function setCorsHeaders($req, $rsp) {
    // http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png
    // Pre-flight
    if ($req->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
        $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
        $this->setMaxAge($req, $rsp);
        $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
        $this->setAllowMethods($req, $rsp);
        $this->setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp);
    }
    else {
        $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
        $this->setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp);
        $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
    }
}
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = new Response("", 200);
        }
        else {
            $response = $next($request);
        }
        $this->setCorsHeaders($request, $response);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

and make sure used it to working CorsMiddleware

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'CorsMiddleware' => App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class,
]);
```